# IPFS Cluster-How to add a sencond Peer on a local Pc

Tags: cluster-computing, ipfs

If i run ipfs and ipfs cluster, i am the only Peer at this Cluster (that's clear).
But how can i add a second Peer from my Pc?
Maybe through antoher Port as the first one?

Thx for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

IPFS Cluster (https://cluster.ipfs.io/documentation/overview/) is mainly used to *"orchestrate IPFS daemons running on different hosts"*, however **yes** you can run two IPFS nodes on the same machine and connect them both to Cluster: [How to run several IPFS nodes on a single machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180171/how-to-run-several-ipfs-nodes-on-a-single-machine).

If you are actually trying to do this for testing, you may be looking for IPTB (https://github.com/ipfs/iptb), which is a tool to *"manage a cluster of sandboxed nodes locally on your computer"* - see the `plugins` section (https://github.com/ipfs/iptb-plugins) for managing individual IPFS nodes within those test clusters.